# Javascript stops working after PHP tag

Tags: javascript, php

I have set session variable 'activeAcademicyearStartsOn' at the time of login.

If we var_dump() the session variable in view.php, the output is like

```
  object(stdClass)#11 (1) { ["$date"]=> object(stdClass)#12 (1) { ["$numberLong"]=> string(13) "1546297200000" } }
```

Now in view.php file, I am trying to get session variable in a javascript code inside javascript tag like

```
  $("#session_start_date").val(getDateString('<?php echo $_SESSION['activeAcademicyearStartsOn'] ?>'));
```

All the Javascript stops working.

```
     <script type="..">
        ...
        ...   
        $(document).ready(function(){  
        ...   
             $("#session_start_date").val(getDateString('<?php echo $_SESSION['activeAcademicyearStartsOn'] ?>'));
        ...
        });

        function getDateString(str)
        {
            if (str == '')
                return;

            var dateObj = new Date(str.$date.$numberLong - 1000);
            var month = dateObj.getMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
            var day = dateObj.getDate();
            var year = dateObj.getFullYear();

            return (month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
        }          
        </script>
```

In order to test, if I put another session variable it works fine like

```
    $("#session_start_date").val('<?php echo $_SESSION['uid'] ?>');
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: $("#session_start_date").val(getDateString("<?php echo $_SESSION['activeAcademicyearStartsOn']; ?>")); Try with "" instead of ''

Comment: shouldn't matter @HP371 - if you think about it ... the inner `'` are processed on the server side

Comment: check the page source ... what appears between `$("#session_start_date").val(getDateString(` and `));` in the browser?

Comment: @JaromandaX: in page source the lines after  $("#session_start_date").val(getDateString('..')); gets eliminated.

Comment: It is upto  $("#session_start_date").val(getDateString(' only,  rest of the code is eliminated i.e closing of script tag..

Comment: eliminated? so, none of the code after `getDateString('` appears at all?

Comment: are you sure its `activeAcademicyearStartsOn` and not `activeAcademicYearStartsOn`?

Comment: yes exactly...  the code appears only upto  $("#session_start_date").val(getDateString(' and the rest of lines are eliminated resulting in an incomplete html

Comment: yes it exactly activeAcademicyearStartsOn here is that line   $_SESSION['activeAcademicyearStartsOn'] = $academicYear->startson;

Comment: if we var_dump this variable, the output is like  object(stdClass)#11 (1) { ["$date"]=> object(stdClass)#12 (1) { ["$numberLong"]=> string(13) "1546297200000" } }

Comment: Please help me ...

Comment: The main cause of the problem is echo... if there other to put date object as a parametre to getDateString function.... Please help me ...

Comment: Go enable proper PHP error reporting (go look it up, if it means nothing to you), and see what error messages you get.

Comment: I think you missing ; at the end in echo function..

Comment: Check the generated javascript in your browsers developer console. Make sure the output doesn't contain any extra characters.

Comment: Actually, your echoing an object in php, into a quoted string in javascript, and your using it as a object in your function. That cant really be expected to work can it?

Comment: If you have not found a solution yet, post the exact **generated** markup

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me your echoing an object in php, into a quoted string in javascript, and your using it as a object in your function.

If you take your php object, and convert it into a javascript object it should work better i think.

```
$("#session_start_date").val(getDateString(<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['activeAcademicyearStartsOn']); ?>));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do 2 things

1. Pass a json_encoded string to the javascript invocation, as mentioned by @Noino .

> `$("#session_start_date").val(getDateString(<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['activeAcademicyearStartsOn']); ?>));`

(This entire peice of code is 1 single line.)

2. Parse this JSON string to make it a javascript object before using the values.

> str = JSON.parse(str);

inside the getDateString() function.