# How to extract value from stdClass string?

Tags: php, serialization

I am getting string after performing some queries in database like

```
 objectString = 'O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:5:"$date";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:11:"$numberLong";s:13:"1546297200000";}}
```

I want to get $numberLong value from stdClass string. I have tried

```
      var dateObj = new Date(objectString.$date.$numberLong - 1000);
```

It throws error message at this line

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$numberLong' of undefined
    at getDateStringObject"

Please help !!!

Comment: This looks like a PHP question by the looks of it. Mind if we update the tags?

Comment: Due to some complex reason I managed to convert stdclass object as string... now i want to extract $numberLong value

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a serialised `stdObject`. If you are getting this value from PHP at any point I would suggest [unserializing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it before returning it back to the javascript.

If done correctly you would be able to access the date as follows:

```
var dateObj = new Date(object.date.numberLong - 1000);
```

If you can't use PHP to unserialise the object, then you could use regex to match the value like so:

```js
var objectString = 'O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:5:"$date";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:11:"$numberLong";s:13:"1546297200000";}}'
var pattern = /("\$numberLong")(.+)("\d+")/g
var match = pattern.exec(objectString);
console.log(match[3]);
```

Comment: How do i unserialize javascript variable inside script tag

Comment: I'm not sure you can unserialise it in javascript.

Comment: I have added a regex option to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`objectString` looks like a serialized object (see [PHP serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)).

You will need to [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it into a PHP object in order be able to use it's properties (like `$numberLong`)

You can take a look at [How to use php serialize() and unserialize()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize) for somewhat of a simple explanation.

Comment: How do i call php unserialize function and pass javascript variable "objectSting" as a parameter inside <script> tag as it is not possible to pass javascript variable  a parametre in php function

Comment: Your problem looks like a combination of this question and the one you ask here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906080/javascript-stops-working-after-php-tag. Do you want the answer here or on that question?

Comment: There is already and answer there that should help. - Do what is recommended there. Update your code to this - $("#session_start_date").val(getDateString(<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['activeAcademicyearStartsOn']); ?>));

Comment: You will need to do 1 more thing. In the javascript function `getDateString`, you will also need to do this - `str = JSON.parse(str); `. This will convert the string to a javascript object that you can use to fetch the `date` and `longNumber` values.